# No podspec found for googleapis in

Tags: cocoapods, speech, podspec

Installing googleapis pod giving error "No podspec found for googleapis in ."

I am trying to installing pod 'googleapis', :path => '.'
but, its getting following error
Analyzing dependencies
Fetching podspec for googleapis from .
[!] No podspec found for googleapis in .

And my pod file is

## Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project

## platform :ios, '8.1'

```
target 'appName' do
  # Uncomment the next line if you're using Swift or would like to use dynamic frameworks
   # use_frameworks!

  # Pods for AppSpeak
   pod 'MBProgressHUD'
   pod 'Fabric'
   pod 'Crashlytics'
   pod 'googleapis', :path => '.'
   end
```

Can anyone help to fix this?

Answer (score 7):

1. Download the sample from [Google-SpeechToText sample in Git](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/ios-docs-samples/tree/master/speech/Swift/Speech-gRPC-Streaming) ,
2. In podfile, do `pod 'googleapis', :path => '.'`
3. Copy 2 things from the sample's main folder named :
    a. googleapis.podspec
    b. google folder
4. Paste these files inside your project folder
5. Then in terminal, locate the project and do `pod install`

To run your demo project, open the BUILDFIXES file inside the sample, and do the fixes as mentioned.
Now you can breathe, the project builds successfully.

Enjoy Coding  ;)

Comment: Thanks Adarsh... "To run your demo project, open the BUILDFIXES file inside the sample, and do the fixes as mentioned." this line helps me. Vai (y)

Answer (score 5):

**Issue:**
[!] No podspec found for googleapis in .

**Solution:**
**Step-1:**
You need to put "googleapis.podspec" file in same directory where your pod file is located.

**Step-2:**
Open terminal and reach to the directory where your pod file located by using "cd" command

**Step-3:**
Then run command "pod update" in terminal

Its done. Your googleapis pod installation begins!!! Hurray!!!

**Download File "googleapis.podspec" from link:** 
https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/ios-docs-samples/files/1378295/googleapis.podspec.zip

Comment: The repository is now only read only.