# Pod install or update fails after installing Google Speech To Text framework for iOS

Tags: ios, cocoapods, speech-recognition, google-speech-api

I have a demo project, did Pod-init -> success.

1. added  `pod 'Alamofire'`  -> pod install -> success
2. added  `pod 'googleapis', :path => '.'`  -> pod install -> success
3. added any other framework, -> pod install -> fails OR did simple pod install/update -> fails

Here is the error :

---

```
[!] ERROR: Parsing unable to continue due to parsing error:
contained in the file located at /Users/ios/Documents/Projects/DemoProj4/Podfile.lock 

PODS:  
  - !ProtoCompiler (3.0.2):
    - Protobuf (~> 3.0)
  - !ProtoCompiler-gRPCPlugin (1.0.2):
    - !ProtoCompiler (= 3.0.2)
    - gRPC-ProtoRPC (= 1.0.2)
  - Alamofire (4.5.1)
  - BoringSSL (7.0):
    - BoringSSL/Implementation (= 7.0)
    - BoringSSL/Interface (= 7.0)
  - BoringSSL/Implementation (7.0):
    - BoringSSL/Interface (= 7.0)
  - BoringSSL/Interface (7.0)
  - googleapis (0.0.1):
    - !ProtoCompiler-gRPCPlugin (~> 1.0.0-pre1.1)
    - googleapis/Messages (= 0.0.1)
    - googleapis/Services (= 0.0.1)
  - googleapis/Messages (0.0.1):
    - !ProtoCompiler-gRPCPlugin (~> 1.0.0-pre1.1)
    - Protobuf
  - googleapis/Services (0.0.1):
    - !ProtoCompiler-gRPCPlugin (~> 1.0.0-pre1.1)
    - googleapis/Messages
    - gRPC-ProtoRPC
  - gRPC (1.0.2):
    - gRPC-Core (= 1.0.2)
    - gRPC-RxLibrary (= 1.0.2)
  - gRPC-Core (1.0.2):
    - gRPC-Core/Implementation (= 1.0.2)
    - gRPC-Core/Interface (= 1.0.2)
  - gRPC-Core/Implementation (1.0.2):
    - BoringSSL (~> 7.0)
    - gRPC-Core/Interface (= 1.0.2)
  - gRPC-Core/Interface (1.0.2)
  - gRPC-ProtoRPC (1.0.2):
    - gRPC (= 1.0.2)
    - gRPC-RxLibrary (= 1.0.2)
    - Protobuf (~> 3.0)
  - gRPC-RxLibrary (1.0.2)
  - Protobuf (3.4.0)

DEPENDENCIES:
  - Alamofire
  - googleapis (from `.`)

EXTERNAL SOURCES:
  googleapis:
    :path: .

SPEC CHECKSUMS:
  !ProtoCompiler: cfad9cbe5299a4923b1c3c8f150818c91efd0b6d
  !ProtoCompiler-gRPCPlugin: ee00d28bb35b26e2657f239833b8f2aa66724f96
  Alamofire: 2d95912bf4c34f164fdfc335872e8c312acaea4a
  BoringSSL: 50035b9d9eeff5529587311782fc57c00ebf13ae
  googleapis: daa20dca7a0097c6c3316fdfd888e0ba1b7c8921
  gRPC: dd3a91e0fb770b9fc4f43d1292fb19f2a2e04158
  gRPC-Core: cc4a7613190ff0bc60a0c1e702ef07cd3f868ae6
  gRPC-ProtoRPC: 11533510522a5e9627883a597a796cfe6bef05f3
  gRPC-RxLibrary: 02cc70b76bc0c5bc622ba27595cca2598d9fe528
  Protobuf: 03eef2ee0b674770735cf79d9c4d3659cf6908e8

PODFILE CHECKSUM: 18b058a3c41c21290645f923f90bea7209df1f49

COCOAPODS: 1.4.0.beta.2
```

---

Then in terminal, I did this: "pod spec lint", and it is showing this:

```
`-> googleapis (0.0.1)
    - ERROR | [iOS] unknown: Encountered an unknown error ([!] /usr/local/bin/git clone https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/ios-docs-samples.git /var/folders/ww/6vrzrmr5719673rcd2dl2h0w0000gn/T/d20171128-3497-1wew1rs --template= --single-branch --depth 1 --branch 0.0.1

Cloning into '/var/folders/ww/6vrzrmr5719673rcd2dl2h0w0000gn/T/d20171128-3497-1wew1rs'...
warning: Could not find remote branch 0.0.1 to clone.
fatal: Remote branch 0.0.1 not found in upstream origin
) during validation.

Analyzed 1 podspec.

[!] The spec did not pass validation, due to 1 error.`
```

---

This is not happening for any other project, but when only this demo project is pod-installed/updated, the issue comes.
Tried all re-installing pods, psych, etc.
Please help

[My Demo Project downloadable link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/d13g7alb9k7wmou/DemoProj6.zip?dl=0)
[Google-SpeechToText sample in Git](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/ios-docs-samples/tree/master/speech/Swift/Speech-gRPC-Streaming)

Comment: possible duplicated https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46703055/no-podspec-found-for-googleapis-in

Comment: @YinKiet my question is not on how to integrate googleapis for speech. Its already integrated. My problem is, now if I install any new pod, delete or update existing pod, it FAILS by saying the error mentioned in my question. And all this happened after googleapis framework was installed successfully in my app.

Comment: share the podfile.

Comment: @AbdulKarim I have edited the question to introduce my downloadable demo-project. It has the podfile and podfile.lock. Can you please have a look at it ?

Comment: @AdarshRoyChoudhary I have implement Text To Speech using googleapis pod. podinstall and project set up like every thing like demo project but can not run project some file not found in pod folder.