# iOS App crashed if installed googleApis with latest version of Firebase through cocoapod

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, crashlytics, firebase-analytics

In my app I have been trying installing latest version of Firebase crashlytics and Analytics pod file and it works fine as well. But the problem occurs when I also installed googleapis pod file (ie. used for speech recognition) with latest version of Firbase crashlytics and Analytics pod file it just crashed the app while launching the app. And the problem is I cannot degrade the Firbase version as it is going to deprecate soon.

Example:-

if installed only below two it worked fine

```
pod 'Firebase/Crashlytics'
pod 'Firebase/Analytics'
```

Crash occurs, if installed below googleapis pod file with Firbase pod files:-

```
pod 'Firebase/Crashlytics'
pod 'Firebase/Analytics'
pod 'googleapis', :path => '.'
```

Any suggestion, how I can resolve this crash?? As I want to use googleapis pod file including latest version of Firebase(Crashlytics and Analytics)

Comment: What kind of error are you getting?

Comment: Getting an error on this nanoPb( nano protocol buffers) which is used for encoding and decoding the input and output stream of data and this protocol buffer is used by the latest version of Firebase library and googeapis. May be it has some dependency, due to which this crash occurs.

Comment: Is this post relevant to your issue? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46703055/no-podspec-found-for-googleapis-in

Comment: Thanks @OlegKodysh, for sharing the link but my issue is not relevant to this link. As I am not facing any compile time issue. I am facing runtime crash issue after installing latest Firebase and googleApis pod files

Comment: What if you run 'pod deintegrate', and only install the googleapis pod without the Firebase ones, does that still cause a crash?

Comment: If I do that then that works fine, the crash only happens when I installed both latest Firbase and googleapis pod

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whoever is facing the same problem, here is the solution for that, all I did was just downgrade the `Firebase Analytics` version to support google apis.